# Lock Table at the begin of a Transaction

Tags: java, database, hibernate, locking

Due to legacy code issues I need to calculate a unique index manually and can't use auto_increment, when inserting a new row to the database.

The problem is that multiple inserts of multiple clients (different machines) can occur simultaneously. Therefore I need to lock the row with the highest id from being read by other transactions while the current transaction is active. Alternatively I could lock the whole table from any reads. Time is not an issue in this case because writes/reads are very rare (<1 op per second)

It tried to set the isolation level to 8 (Serializable), but then MySQL throws a DeadLockException. Interestingly the SELECT to determine the next ID is still done, which contradicts my understanding of serializable.

Also setting the LockMode to PESSIMISTIC_READ of the select, doesn't seem to help.

```
public void insert(T entity) {
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    try {
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();

            int id = 0;
            TypedQuery<MasterDataComplete> query = em.createQuery(
                    "SELECT m FROM MasterDataComplete m ORDER BY m.id DESC", MasterDataComplete.class);
            query.setMaxResults(1);
            query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
            List<MasterDataComplete> results = query.getResultList();
            if (!results.isEmpty()) {
                MasterDataComplete singleResult = results.get(0);

                id = singleResult.getId() + 1;
            }

            entity.setId(id);

            em.persist(entity);
            transaction.commit();
        } finally {
            if (transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Some words to the application:
It is Java-Standalone, runs on multiple clients which connect to the same DB Server and it should work with multiple DB servers (Sybase Anywhere, Oracle, Mysql, ...)

Currently the only idea I've got left is just to do the insert and catch the Exception that occurs when the ID is already in use and try again. This works because I can assume that the column is set to primary key/unique.

Comment: Do you have the option of implementing a service and exposing the database through that it?

Comment: No sadly not. The whole architecture is a mess (up to 15 years old) and all clients connect to the database directly.
When I would implement it now I would go for a central server that connects to the DB and thin clients which just request and show data from the server. But sadly the client has over 200k LOCs and completely rewriting it is not an option. :(

Comment: What about generating a unique identifier each time? Composed of time-based part plus random part. Or cryptographically safe unique identifier. No transaction isolation nor optimistic locking problems, and easy to implement.

Comment: And yet another idea - use a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with **PESSIMISTIC_READ** you are blocking others **UPDATE** on the row with the highest ID. If you want to block other's **SELECT** you need to use **PESSIMISTIC_WRITE**.

I know it seems strange since you're not going to UPDATE that row.. ..but if you want the other blocks while executing a SELECT you should lye and say: "Hay all.. ..I read this row and will UPDATE it".. ..so that they will not be allowed to read that row sinche the DB engine thinks that you will modify it before the commit.

SERIALIZABLE itself according to the documentation converts all plain SELECT statements to SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE so does not more than what you're already doing explicitly.